# How to re-link files in iron.io?

Tags: bash, file, iron.io

I'm trying to upload the following files and linksto iron.io:

[image]

After downloading the files from iron.io that were originally uploaded, I can see that the links are turned into these files

[image]

How do I maintain the links so that they are not turned into files in the process of uploading to iron.io.

Ideally, I can run this bash script on iron.io to solve for this:

```
rm libicudata.so.50 && ln -s libicudata.so.50.1.2 libicudata.so.50
rm libicui18n.so.50 && ln -s libicui18n.so.50.1.2 libicui18n.so.50
rm libicuio.so.50 && ln -s libicuio.so.50.1.2 libicuio.so.50
rm libicule.so.50 && ln -s libicule.so.50.1.2 libicule.so.50
rm libiculx.so.50 && ln -s libiculx.so.50.1.2 libiculx.so.50
rm libicutu.so.50 && ln -s libicutu.so.50.1.2 libicutu.so.50
rm libicuuc.so.50 && ln -s libicuuc.so.50.1.2 libicuuc.so.50
```

For reference, this is my worker:

```
# set the runtime language. Python workers use "python"
runtime "python"
# exec is the file that will be executed:
exec "test.py"

stack 'selenium'
remote
file "iron.json"
file "test.py"
dir '/Library/dataextract/'
```

I upload this worker with the following bash script:

```
iron_worker upload test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "upload" a symlink. It's a symbolic link, there's no way to "send" it anywhere. You can create a tarball and upload that instead.

```
cd /path/to/the/files && tar cvf libs.tar *
```

Then on the receiving server, untar the files:

```
cd /path/to/the/files && tar xvf libs.tar
```

Assuming the symlinks are relative and pointing to files in the same directory, they will probably be successfully preserved. If they are absolute, they may be pointing to the wrong location.